# Sitecore Forms access to Form response

Tags: sitecore-forms

Is there a way to programmatically access the submitted forms response of the user?

Scenario:
User A submits a Sitecore Form and is redirected to a page where he can see all his answers to the form.

Comment: welcome to sse!. You would need a custom submit action to store the User responses/answers in the form to a ViewBag/ViewData. It could be used to display the data on submission

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `Redirect to Page` action you won't be able to access the submitted data. One solution would need to create a custom action that will save the form's values in Session/Cache/TempData and would be executed before the `Redirect to Page` one.

You can find more details on how to implement a custom action in the sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action.html. Your submit button would look like this:
[image]

Another solution would be to have only one custom action that would be reusing the Redirect Page implementation:

```
public class CustomRedirectToPage : SubmitActionBase<RedirectActionData>
{
    public CustomRedirectToPage(ISubmitActionData submitActionData) : base(submitActionData)
    {
    }

    protected override bool Execute(RedirectActionData data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)formSubmitContext, nameof(formSubmitContext));
        if (data == null || !(data.ReferenceId != Guid.Empty))
            return false;
        Item obj = Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(data.ReferenceId));
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        foreach (var viewModel in formSubmitContext.Fields)
        {
            var type = viewModel.GetType();
            var field = (InputViewModel<string>)viewModel;
            var value = field.Value;

           //store the field values
        }

        ItemUrlBuilderOptions urlBuilderOptions = this.LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlBuilderOptions();
        urlBuilderOptions.SiteResolving = new bool?(Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving);
        formSubmitContext.RedirectUrl = new UrlString(this.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(obj, urlBuilderOptions)).ToString();
        formSubmitContext.RedirectOnSuccess = true;
        formSubmitContext.Abort();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that the above code only reads the simple string fields types, for the others you can use a more generic method similar to the one described https://madhuanbalagan.com/generic-method-to-read-values-from-any-type-of-form-fields